# shop grid in html5

Tags: html, css

i would like to build a "grid of products" in html5 and i'm not sure what new html5 attribute elements should i use. I've seen a mixture of figure and span or use of tables ( like i was doing a long time ago ).

Code example:

```
<figure class="span4 slide">
    <a href="book-detail.html"><img src="images/image25.jpg" alt="" class="pro-img"></a>
        <span class="title"><a href="book-detail.html">A Walk Across The Sun</a></span>
        <span class="rating-bar"><img src="images/rating-star.png" alt="Rating Star"></span>
        <div class="cart-price">
            <a class="cart-btn2" href="cart.html">Add to Cart</a>
            <span class="price">$129.90</span>
        </div>
</figure>
```

My question is what could i use to build a grid and be semantical and use the power of html5 .

Answer (score 0):

I don't think figure is appropriate for an entire product description, but your question is largely subjective. It's also depended on the larger structure of your HTML. Personally, I'd probably use a `section` for each product, and break groups of products into `articles` if appropriate.

That said, I'd look to HTML5 developer guides rather than asking such a specific question here.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#new-elements

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Sections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document

Comment: i was thinking using article combined with div's.. :-) list would be ok .. :-) but still looking for more options and advices :D

Comment: Answer changed slightly. I think `section` might work for products.

Comment: ok so in the end i will go for this one. since i'm using a css framework i will combine the "col-x" with figure and figcaption for picture and description with a div for add to cart and price and some span elements around :D just to be a little bit semnatic there
I'll post an example as soon as i'm done :-)